# Counting the number of circular rods in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I want to count the number of metal rods in an image using image processing. The images are all similar to this one:

[image: image of rods]

I thought of using Hough Circle Transform, but the rods aren't precisely circular and also there are imperfections on the faces. Another idea was to use watershed algorithm. I took following steps:

1. Grayscale conversion
2. a CLAHE enhancement
3. Pyramid Mean Shift Filter to remove the texture and irregularities
4. Applied a gaussian blur.
5. Otsu's Thresholding

Result:

[image: here]

**upper image is after 4, lower after 5**

Clearly, I cannot use this image for Watershed. 
I then tried using a simple thresholding, which gives better results, but still not accurate enough. Also I want the counting algorithm to be independent of the image used, and that means simple thresholding won't do.

I searched the net for algorithms to detect circular objects, but they all seem to be dependent on the segmentation or edge detection. I don't understand how to proceed from this point. Am I missing something basic here?

Edit: The basic preprocessing code:

```
img = cv2.imread('testc.jpg')
img = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img, 21, 51)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(7,7))
cl1 = clahe.apply(img)
cl1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(cl1, (5,5), 1)
ret3,thresh = cv2.threshold(cl1,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Watershed:

```
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
localMax = peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=35,
    labels=thresh)

# perform a connected component analysis on the local peaks,
# using 8-connectivity, then appy the Watershed algorithm
markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-D, markers, mask=thresh)
print("[INFO] {} unique segments found".format(len(np.unique(labels)) - 1))

# loop over the unique labels returned by the Watershed
# algorithm
for label in np.unique(labels):
    # if the label is zero, we are examining the 'background'
    # so simply ignore it
    if label == 0:
        continue

    # otherwise, allocate memory for the label region and draw
    # it on the mask
    mask = np.zeros(gray.shape, dtype="uint8")
    mask[labels == label] = 255

    # detect contours in the mask and grab the largest one
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # draw a circle enclosing the object
    ((x, y), r) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img, "#{}".format(label), (int(x) - 10, int(y)),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Code for Watershed algorithm I took mostly from pyimagesearch I am sorry for not giving the link, I am allowed to post only two links currently (and No Images).

This is not the only thing that I have tried, but is the best approach currently.

Comment: I swapped [tag:counting] out with [tag:matlab] since a language tag is more likely to get you views on this question. It looks very nice now, hope someone will be able to answer it eventually!

Comment: @Miki um... that is Matlab .-. is it not?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts no, it's python

Comment: *facepalm* I'm sorry, thank you for fixing that. It looked like Matlab to me. **edit** and now I feel even more stupid because I googled Matlab comment syntax and it's `%`, not `#`...

Comment: Instead of converting the RGB to grayscale, you might try using a single channel from other colorspaces---preview them to see which channels from which spaces seem to carry the most information about the ends of the aluminum. Also, maybe try using a different normalization / equalization step. How well does `equalizeHist()` compare to the CLAHE equalization?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I had tried to convert the image to HSV. The problem was that although it gave a lot better results, it still does not give required accuracy, which is very high; and it is image dependent, in one image H will give you better results, in other, S and like that. Equalizehist is, in general, poorer than CLAHE.